Trying to alter the falling code Matrix texture from CGMatter's gumroad so it says one sentence in order, but I cant figure it out
Just watched CGmatters matrix tutorial on how to make the matrix falling code texture, and with my very limited knowledge of nodes I have pretty much no idea what is going on and how the texture works, especially with the tutorial rushing through everything as fast as it can. The texture he is creating was luckily provided for free on Gumroad, but I need to slightly alter it.
All I need to do is have each line saying 'crash the world' rather than having random changing characters. I switched out the image texture of the letters with my own saying crash the world, but the letters are all still random. In the tutorial he mentioned something about adding randomness using White noise textures, but I couldn't figure out how to remove any of these to have each line have the sentence properly.
The blend file can be downloaded here, if anyone with better node knowledge than me could set this up for me, it would help a lot

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

One thing about the YouTube tutorials that can help is that one can replay the parts of them they don't understand as many times as needed until they can do what is being shown. Also if the pace is too fast one can view the video at a much slower speed.

the matrix effect shows random symbols/letters. If you want to make them write a word or sentence you need to define the words somehow, probably with the help of the image texture. Do you want to have no random characters at all?

Can you share the longimagecsd.png? It's not included in the blend file.
